# Spark structured streamed data not saved in to csv file

Tags: java, spark-structured-streaming

when i do aggregation and then write to file, I am getting following error : "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;"

below is the code snippet

```
Dataset<Row> ds2= ds1
.withWatermark("timestamp", "1 minutes")
.groupByKey((MapFunction<DeviceData, String>) value -> value.getDeviceType(), Encoders.STRING())
.agg(typed.avg((MapFunction<DeviceData, Double>) value -> value.getSignal()))
.withColumn("timestamp", current_timestamp())
.withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes");

StreamingQuery query = ds2.writeStream()
.outputMode("complete")
.format("console")
.trigger(Trigger.Once())
.start();
query.awaitTermination();
```

is working but the same i tried to sink into file as below

```
StreamingQuery query = ds2
.writeStream()
.format("csv")
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
.option("path", "D://output")
.option("checkpointLocation", "D://checkpoint")
.start();
query.awaitTermination();
```

is showing the error, "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;" while try to invoke .start()

As I am new to Spark Streaming through java, any support towards this issue is my appreciable.
Expectation: Make the result written in to csv file.